# Converting date times in POSIXct gives screwy result?

Tags: r, time

I'm doing some extracting of data from a database, and running the results through rehsape2.  For some reason this is mangling the POSIXct datetime stamps into numeric.  No Problem I think, you can just turn them back, except I'm an hour out.

Here's a minimal example

```
foo<-as.POSIXct("2011-04-04 14:18:58")
as.numeric(foo)     #gives 130192318
bar<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric(foo), 
                tz=Sys.timezone(),
                origin=as.POSIXct(
                  strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")))
as.numeric(bar)     #gives 130192318 identical !
foo     #Gives "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST"
bar     #Gives "2011-04-04 13:18:58 UTC"
```

Obviously foo and bar are numerically identical, but R thinks foo needs to be displayed as BST and bar as UTC.  How do I get both displayed as BST.  This doesn't work either;

```
as.POSIXct(bar, tz="BST")   #still gives "2011-04-04 13:18:58 UTC"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what's going on.  `bar` is created using `as.POSIXct.numeric`, which is defined as:

```
as.POSIXct.numeric
function (x, tz = "", origin, ...) 
{
    if (missing(origin)) 
        stop("'origin' must be supplied")
    as.POSIXct(origin, tz = tz, ...) + x
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You supply an origin that is a `POSIXct` object.  That means the `as.POSIXct` call in `as.POSIXct.numeric` dispatches to `as.POSIXct.default`, which is defined as:

```
as.POSIXct.default
function (x, tz = "", ...) 
{
    if (inherits(x, "POSIXct")) 
        return(x)
    if (is.character(x) || is.factor(x)) 
        return(as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...))
    if (is.logical(x) && all(is.na(x))) 
        return(.POSIXct(as.numeric(x)))
    stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class \"POSIXct\"", 
        deparse(substitute(x))))
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`x` is a `POSIXct` class object (the `origin` you supplied in your initial call), so it is simply returned and the `tz=` argument is ignored.

---

UPDATE:
Here's how you can convert `foo` back to `POSIXct` with the appropriate time zone.

```
(foo <- as.POSIXct("2011-04-04 14:18:58", tz="GB"))
# [1] "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST"
.POSIXct(as.numeric(foo), tz="GB")
# [1] "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the kludge I've employed to get round this.  By specifying the origin as the current time minus the numeric version of the current time, the timezones don't seem to get screwed up.

```
foo<-as.POSIXct("2011-04-04 14:18:58")
as.numeric(foo)     #gives 130192318
bar<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric(foo), tz="GB", origin=Sys.time()-as.numeric(Sys.time()))
as.numeric(bar)     #gives 130192318 identical !
foo     #Gives "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST"
[1] "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST"
bar     #Gives "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST"
[1] "2011-04-04 14:18:58 BST
```

Comment: I misunderstood what you wanted.  I've updated my answer with a solution you may find less cludgey.